# Java: Get the line of code defining an object

Tags: java, reflection

In a relatively complex project I have many runnables defined like

```
Runnable foo = () -> {
// bar
}
```

'foo' is passed through several objects and executed at some point.
Now for debugging purposes, I'd like a smooth way of retrieving in what file and in what line the runnable has been initialized and that without adding any code into the runnable (like working with the stacktrace).

In other words, I need a function which tells where an object has been created.
Is there any reflection method in Java for this purpose?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing.  The closest you can get is the class name, which will be something like `Test$$Lambda$1/1921595561`.

Comment: What is your real goal here?  I'm sure you're not just looking to do this for the sake of it, but to solve some larger issue.

Comment: @JoeC Well, not a direct issue but more like an organizing concept. In fact it is a JFX application and I'd like to be redirected to the codeline which defines a certain runnable which is related to a node when I click that node.
However am thinking currently of creating some datastructure to keep track of this 'manually'.